# php: how does single quote and double quote work together

Tags: php, mysql

Below codes is taken from one tutorial:

```
 <?php
// user input that uses SQL Injection
$name_bad = "' OR 1'"; 

// our MySQL query builder, however, not a very safe one
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name_bad'";

// display what the new query will look like, with injection
echo "Injection: " . $query_bad;
```

In front end, it shows:

```
Injection: SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '' OR 1''
```

Question:

why it shows `username = '' OR 1''`?

Comment: @David — No, don't. The `mysql_*` library is deprecated and shouldn't be used at all and [there are better ways to protect against SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) than escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See explanation in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PHP strings quoted with `"` characters interpolate variables and treat `'` characters as literals.

`$name_bar` is a string that contains `'` characters.

When it is interpolated, all the characters in it are placed where the variable was.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP if in double quotes you write any variable it is replace by value of the variable as perfectly done by PHP in your case

```
// user input that uses SQL Injection
$name_bad = "' OR 1'"; 

// our MySQL query builder, however, not a very safe one
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name_bad'";
```

if I replace the value $name_bad with ' OR 1' then it would become

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '' OR 1'';
```

and if you want to remove the extra ' before and after your query then you have write your query as:

```
// our MySQL query builder, however, not a very safe one
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = $name_bad";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're basically just concatting the strings.

```
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name_bad'";
```

is the same as

```
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '' OR 1''";
```

since `$name_bad` is `' OR 1'`.

Answer (score 1):

It does that because `$name_bad` includes the single quotes, and you have inserted it between another set of quotes in the other string.

For best practice, use:

`$string = sprintf('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = \'%s\'', ' OR 1');`

On to the SQL however, it will need to be sanitized.

If you are using PDO, the `bindParam` method will automatically prevent SQL injection (it states).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php